# laravel | html - How to set default select option in form based on db field?

Tags: html, forms, laravel, select, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 and I have a select field in my record update form for gender.
I have already got the gender value of the record being updated.
It is `{{$customer_profile->gender}}`

But I cant figure out how to set default of this select field in my form based on the value of `{{$customer_profile->last_name}}` which is either `m` or `f`

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Gender</label>
             <select class="form-control" name="gender">
                     <option value="m">Male</option>
                     <option value="f">Female</option>
             </select>
 </div>
```

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you mean how to set `selected` attribute based on `$customer_profile->gender` value. You can do this:

```
<option value="m" {{ $customer_profile->gender === 'm' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Male</option>
<option value="f" {{ $customer_profile->gender === 'f' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Female</option>
```